# JVM: Is it possible hotfix/patch production code via remote Clojure repl?

Tags: clojure, jvm, read-eval-print-loop

In [Clojure for Java Programmers Part 1](https://youtu.be/P76Vbsk_3J0?t=1254) talk Rich Hickey mentions this as one of the benefits of Clojure:

> If you build an application with some access to the ability to load
>   code - either a remote repl connection or some way to do that. Your
>   running production systems will have this capability to have fixes
>   loaded into running programs.

I'm wondering how easy it is in practice. Let's say I know there is a bug in one function and I want to redefine/override it in production via remote repl

- Is it possible?
- Will the overridden version stay active after I exit the repl?
- Is this behavior in all JVM application containers?

I don't have any experience of using JVM in production and that's the reason for asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Yes, I would recommend watching [The Joys and Perils of Interactive Development - Stuart Sierra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RaFcpNiYCo) he tells a story of NASA hotfixing a satellite in space using the REPL.

> Will the overridden version stay active after I exit the repl?

When you reevaluate the function the changes will apply everywhere so for example

```
(defn add1 [x]
  (+ x 2))

(defn foo [x]
  (add1 x))

(foo 1)
```

Notice `(foo 1) => 3` if you fix and reevaluate `add1` then run again `(foo 1) => 2`

Comment: We do this occasionally at work -- apply a hotfix to production via a connected REPL -- but it is, of course, risky since you are modifying a running application that people are (presumably) actively using. It's worth noting that while the changes applied via the REPL remain in place once you disconnect from the process, the changes are only applied in-memory and if you restart the process, it will lose those changes (because it will start up with whatever version of the code is on disk).